# Android Program crahses on start

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have been following [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html) series on Open GL for android, but whenever I run the first program it crashes on start. I might have missed something in their code, but I triple checked. does it have something to do with the activity xml file?

here is the complete log cat info

```
04-20 15:53:13.695: D/OpenGLRenderer(2229): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-20 15:53:13.698: D/(2229): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42b3e10, tid 2229
04-20 15:53:13.791: D/Atlas(2229): Validating map...
04-20 15:53:13.844: D/(2229): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42b3eb0, tid 2245
04-20 15:53:13.955: I/OpenGLRenderer(2229): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-20 15:53:14.002: D/OpenGLRenderer(2229): Enabling debug mode 0
04-20 15:53:14.025: W/EGL_emulation(2229): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-20 15:53:14.025: W/OpenGLRenderer(2229): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb431f980, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-20 15:53:14.119: D/(2229): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42b3ad0, tid 2244
04-20 15:53:14.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2229): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 157
04-20 15:53:14.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2229): Process: com.test, PID: 2229
04-20 15:53:14.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2229): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
04-20 15:53:14.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:869)
04-20 15:53:14.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1023)
04-20 15:53:14.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1400)
04-20 15:53:14.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

**MyGLActivity.class**

```
 package com.test;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.opengl.*;
    import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
    public class MyGLActivity extends Activity {

        private GLSurfaceView glView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
            glView.setRenderer(new MyGlRenderer(this));
            this.setContentView(glView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            glView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            glView.onResume();
        }


    }
```

**MyGlRenderer.class**

```
package com.test;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.content.Context;
public class MyGlRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
    Context context;

    public  MyGlRenderer(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl,EGLConfig config){
        gl.glClearColor(100.0f,50.0f,75.0f,1.0f);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if(height == 0){ height = 1;}
        float aspect = (float)width / height;


        gl.glViewport(0,0,width,height);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, aspect, 0.1f,100.f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    }

}
```

Comment: What is the log output in the moment the app crashes?

Comment: Fatal Exception: GLThread152

Comment: If you are using Android Studio the go to Tool-->Android-->Android Device Monitor and please provide us full LogCat

Comment: The rest is: Process: com.test, PID: 2118 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EGLHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java : 1023) at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1400) at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:12 39)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite documentation does not specify as mandatory, it seems sometimes you must call [`GLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLConfigChooser(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) before `GLSurfaceView.setRenderer`

Try out this initialization code:

```java
public class MyGLActivity extends Activity {
    //...    
    private GLSurfaceView glView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        glView.setRenderer(new MyGlRenderer(this));
        this.setContentView(glView);
    }
    //...
}
```